# IF ( Count(*) > 1)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to look through two tables TableA and TableB get print out the TableA.ID of any that show more than 1 count. TableA looks like this:

```
ID  |  Code
------------
1   |  A
2   |  B
3   |  C
```

Table B Looks like

```
ID  |  AID |   EffectiveDate  |  ExpirationDate
------------------------------------------------
1   |  1   |  2012-01-01      |  2012-12-31
2   |  1   |  2012-01-01      |  2012-12-31
3   |  2   |  2012-01-01      |  2012-12-31
4   |  3   |  2012-01-01      |  2012-12-31
```

The Query I am using looks like this:

```
DECLARE @MoreThanOne varchar(250)
SET @MoreThanOne = ''
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT TableB.ID
        ,TableB.EffectiveDate
        ,TableB.ExpirationDate
     FROM TableB
     WHERE TableB.AID = TableA.ID
        and GETDATE() Between TableB.EffectiveDate and TableB.ExpirationDate
) 
GROUP BY TableA.Code) > 1)
BEGIN
--SET @MoreThanOne = @MoreThanOne + TableA.Code + CHAR(10)

END


PRINT @MoreThanOne
```

I know that my nested Query works when reworked it will print the counts for all in the unique codes in TableA.
I know that I can not use what I commented out because i don't have access to TableA.Code.
My question is there another way to do this or how can I get access to TableA.Code for the Message MoreThanOne.

Thanks For the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will get you the codes for all AIDs that are duplicated in table B:

```
SELECT Code
FROM TableA
WHERE AID IN
(
    SELECT AID
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY AID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

You may also wish to add the `WHERE` condition that have in your stored procedure to the inner select.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.Code, Count(*) As Cnt

         FROM TableB, TableA
         WHERE TableB.AID = TableA.ID
            and GETDATE() Between TableB.EffectiveDate and TableB.ExpirationDate
         GROUP BY TableA.ID, TableA.Code
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply, with no join:

```
SELECT tableb.AID
FROM TableB
WHERE GETDATE() Between TableB.EffectiveDate and TableB.ExpirationDate
group by tableb.AID
having count(*) > 1
```

This simply aggregates tableB by AID, returning the values with more than one record.  You only need to join to TableA if you want the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should do you:

```
select Code      = a.Code ,
       Frequency = count(*)
from table_a a
join table_b b on b.aid = a.id
              and current_timestamp between b.EffectiveDate and b.ExpirationDate
group by a.Code
having count(*) > 1
order by 2 desc -- order in descending sequence by frequency
         1      -- then ascending sequence by code
```